# T-SQL : How to Select Multiple Field In SubQuery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I have two Tables **INVOICE** and **CUSTOMER**
in the **INVOICE** table i have a reference of the **CUSTOMER** table (**CustomerId**) i need when i create an invoice view retrive the **NAME** and **EMAIL** and other field in one same subquery

***NB : I CANNOT USE JOIN***

What i doing now is

```
SELECT 
InvoiceId, 
(SELECT FullName FROM Customer WHERE CustomerId = CustomerId) AS CustomerFullName, 
(SELECT Email FROM Customer WHERE CustomerId = CustomerId) AS CustomerEmail 
...
FROM
InVoice
```

What i need is

```
SELECT 
InvoiceId, 
(SELECT FullName, Email, ....  FROM Customer WHERE CustomerId = CustomerId) AS CustomerFullName, CustomerEmail, ....  
FROM
InVoice
```

Is this kind of sub query possible ?

Comment: "** *NB : I CANNOT USE JOIN* ** " I have to ask; Why? On a separate, note, no, you cannot return multiple values in a sub query (either multiple rows, or multiple columns). They must return a single value. Using a `JOIN` is the answer here. I cannot think of any reason why you would want to use you, and using a subquery on **every** column will cause terrible performance. The table would need to be (at least) scanned for each column's value.

Comment: The right things is i don't want to use it. i try to refactor a lot of sql query write in the last decade with the first style. and i look for a easy way to refactor these query without having to write JOIN I' will need to check all foreign keys to decide when to use CROSS, LEFT, INNER ... JOIN

Comment: @JeanClaudeADIBA If it's working don't change it. I don't like the deprecated implicit join but when I find one I try not to mess with it unless strict necessary. If you can program C#, Delphi, VB, Java etc it's easy to create a semi-auto sql rewriter, of course you still needs to do lots of manual stuff and works better if all was written in same style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this uses `join`.  If, say, the "j" key on your keyboard is broken, you can express this using `apply`:

```
SELECT i.InvoiceId, c.*
FROM InVoice i OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT c.FullName, c.Email, . . .
      FROM Customer c
      WHERE c.CustomerId = i.CustomerId
     ) c;
```

Comment: If the "j" on your keyboard is broken, personally, I'd suggest one of the following: *1. Buy a new keyboard. 2. Find a page with a `j` on it and copy and paste it into your query designer. 3. Use the onscreen keyboard.* I really can't think of a "good" reason as to why the OP can't use a `JOIN` here.

Comment: Ok thanks for your advice. as @Larnu said i have some performance issues. and i refactor all my queries (note that i'm not DBA). 
With the fact that i need in the query result all rows of the main table (invoice) either customerid is null between OUTER APPLY and JOIN which give me the best performance

Comment: @JeanClaudeADIBA again, why are you so resistant to using `JOIN`s? Your performance issues are likely not because of the existence of the `JOIN` construct in your queries but rather fundamental design problems with the tables/queries, poor indexing, server configuration, or poor usage of SQL (the language).

Answer (score 2):

To respond to the OP's statement of

> The right things is i don't want to use it.

Why would you **not** want to use a `JOIN`? Using subqueries is, quite literally, an **awful** idea... As example, let's take a very simple query on the WideWorldImporters Datbase from Microsoft:

```
SELECT I.InvoiceID,
       O.OrderID,
       O.OrderDate, O.ExpectedDeliveryDate
FROM sales.Invoices I
     JOIN sales.Orders O ON I.OrderID = O.OrderID
WHERE I.InvoiceID BETWEEN 1 AND 1000;
```

With Statistics Time and IO on, this results in:

```
Table 'Orders'. Scan count 0, logical reads 3000, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. 

Table 'Invoices'. Scan count 1, logical reads 182, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. 


SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 4 ms, elapsed time = 4 ms.
```

About to be expected then. Now, let's use your method (with subqueries):

```
SELECT I.InvoiceID,
       (SELECT O.OrderID FROM sales.Orders O WHERE I.OrderID = O.OrderID) AS OrderID,
       (SELECT O.OrderDate FROM sales.Orders O WHERE I.OrderID = O.OrderID) AS OrderDate,
       (SELECT O.ExpectedDeliveryDate FROM sales.Orders O WHERE I.OrderID = O.OrderID) AS ExpectedDeliveryDate
FROM sales.Invoices I     
WHERE I.InvoiceID BETWEEN 1 AND 1000;
```

And the cost?

```
Table 'Orders'. Scan count 0, logical reads 9000, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. 

Table 'Invoices'. Scan count 1, logical reads 182, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. 


SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 10 ms, elapsed time = 10 ms.
```

Well, no surprise, the reads **tripled**, from 3000 to 9000! Also, the execution time is more than double. Just because we used a subquery for each column.

Now, just to prove a further point, let's bring in the Customer table shall we, and see how "badly" this goes:

```
PRINT 'Using JOIN';
SELECT I.InvoiceID,
       C.CustomerName,
       C.DeliveryPostalCode,
       O.OrderID,
       O.OrderDate, O.ExpectedDeliveryDate
FROM sales.Invoices I
     JOIN sales.Orders O ON I.OrderID = O.OrderID
     JOIN sales.Customers C ON O.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
WHERE I.InvoiceID BETWEEN 1 AND 1000;

PRINT 'Using Subqueries'
SELECT I.InvoiceID,
       (SELECT C.Customername FROM sales.Customers C WHERE C.CustomerID = (SELECT O.CustomerID FROM sales.Orders O WHERE I.OrderID = O.OrderID)) AS CustomerName,
       (SELECT C.DeliveryPostalCode FROM sales.Customers C WHERE C.CustomerID = (SELECT O.CustomerID FROM sales.Orders O WHERE I.OrderID = O.OrderID)) AS DeliveryPostalCode,
       (SELECT O.OrderID FROM sales.Orders O WHERE I.OrderID = O.OrderID) AS OrderID,
       (SELECT O.OrderDate FROM sales.Orders O WHERE I.OrderID = O.OrderID) AS OrderDate,
       (SELECT O.ExpectedDeliveryDate FROM sales.Orders O WHERE I.OrderID = O.OrderID) AS ExpectedDeliveryDate
FROM sales.Invoices I     
WHERE I.InvoiceID BETWEEN 1 AND 1000;
```

The results?

```
Using JOIN 


SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms. 

    (1000 rows affected) 

    Table 'Workfile'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. 

    Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. 

    Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. 

    Table 'Customers'. Scan count 1, logical reads 40, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. 

    Table 'Orders'. Scan count 0, logical reads 3000, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. 

    Table 'Invoices'. Scan count 1, logical reads 182, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. 


SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 9 ms, elapsed time = 8 ms. 

    Using Subqueries 


SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms. 

    (1000 rows affected) 

    Table 'Orders'. Scan count 0, logical reads 15000, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. 

    Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. 

    Table 'Customers'. Scan count 2000, logical reads 80000, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. 

    Table 'Invoices'. Scan count 1, logical reads 182, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. 


SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 2028 ms, elapsed time = 2029 ms.
```

Look at that execution time! Over 2 seconds! it took 9ms to do the same query using a `JOIN`. And look at those reads! 15000 of the Orders table, and 80000 of the Customers table. Using a `JOIN` meant they were at 3000 and 40 respectively.

So, I have to ask, again, "Why do you not want to use a `JOIN`?" There is no good reason to do so. Even without Keys, and indexes, the performance is exponentially better. What you are doing, in honesty, is a terrible mistake. Please, please, please, rethink about using subqueries.